# AdS$_D$ relation killing vector and boost

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

I am following "Supergravity" from Freedman and Van Proeyen and I am working on problem 22.8 therein.

They embedded AdS$_D$ in $\mathbb{R}^{D+1}$ as $$f(Y)=-(Y^0)^2+\sum_{i=1}^{D-1} (Y^i)^2 - (Y^D)^2 = \eta_{AB} Y^A Y^B= -L^2.$$
Then they define $$L_{AB} = Y_A \partial_B - Y_B \partial_A$$ and they realise the Lie algebra of ${\rm SO}(D-1,2)$. Then they go to inherent coordinates $u, x^i$ ($i = 1, ..., D-2$) defined by
\begin{align*}
Y^0 &= L u x^0 \\
Y^i &= L u x^i \\
Y^{D-1} &= \frac{1}{2u} (-1+u^2(L^2-x^2)) \\
Y^{D} &= \frac{1}{2u} (1+u^2(L^2+x^2)) \\
x^2 &= -(x^0)^2 + \sum_{i=1}^{D-2} (x^i)^2
\end{align*} and $z = 1/u$

Then they talk about the scale transformation $\delta x^0 = \rho x^0 $,$\delta x^i = \rho x^i $ and $\delta z = \rho z$ for an infinitesimal parameter $\rho$.

I found that the killing vector corresponding to this scaling is $x^A\partial_A$ ($A=0,1,..., D-2, z$, where $x^z=z$).

Now, I need to show that this killing vector corresponds to $L_{D(D-1)}$ (what they call a boost). To do so, I determined $dY^0,dY^i,dY^D,d(x^2)$ in terms of the new coordinates $x^0,x^i,u$(or $z$). I did this so that I could find $\partial_D$ in terms of $\partial_u$ and $\partial_0,\partial_i$. To find these, I need $\frac{\partial u}{\partial Y^D}$. However, what I can calculate from $dY^D$ is $\frac{\partial Y^D}{\partial u}$. Then, I need to "invert" the matrix with derivatives of the $Y$ to the new coordinates, to find the derivatives of the new coordinates with respect to the $Y$.

The problem I ran into with this is that there is one coordinate more for the embedded coordinates in comparison to the inherent coordinates (which makes sense). So I can never invert the derivative matrix. Then I thought that I could use $d(f(Y)) = 0$ as extra condition, however, this seems to give no extra information.

Does anyone have any tips on how to proceed and show that $L_{D(D-1)}$ agrees with $x^A\partial_A$? If other ideas or other approaches are possible, they are more than welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by starting from the Killing vector $x^A \partial_A$ and manipulating this expression starting from the differentials of the $Y$ and the chain rule. It works out perfectly.